# Refresh Dom object after navigation within the same webpage

Tags: c#, html, dom

I have a website with more than one page. After i click on continue in the first page am redirected to second page. It has DOM elements and so using webbrowser document object i am,retrieving the controls. But after navigation sometimes the document object holds the first page controls only. Hence throws a null exception. Kindly advice

Comment: What kind of objects are "document object"?

Comment: I mean an Html document